# View уже имеет родителя

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

У меня возникла проблема. Я создаю view, который позже хочу добавить в слой, но при попытке его добавления пишется, что данный view уже имеет родителя.

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

```
val adView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_unified_choose,null) as UnifiedNativeAdView

var builder: AdLoader.Builder = AdLoader.Builder(applicationContext, resources.getString(R.string.NativeAd))
builder.forUnifiedNativeAd { unifiedNativeAd -> 
    populateUnifiedNativeAdView(unifiedNativeAd, adView) 
}

val adOptions = NativeAdOptions.Builder().build()

val adLoader = builder.withNativeAdOptions(adOptions).build()

adLoader?.loadAd(getRequest())

val holder = hold as AdHolder
holder.frame.post {
    holder.frame.removeView(adView)
    holder.frame.addView(adView)
}
```

Comment: невозможно добавить один объект View дважды, ищите ошибку в коде

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте это, возможно поможет

```
if (adView.getParent() != null) {
    (adView.getParent() as? ViewGroup)?.removeView(adView)
}
holder.frame.addView(adView)
```